# How to Show Products Custom attribute value in cart and checkout summary?

Tags: magento2, cart, onestepcheckout

I Have a custom attribute for all products. its integer types. and i want show attributes total value in cart and checkout summary. please help.

[image]

Comment: You can show the attribute values in your cart summary but how do you want? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Suppose I have a Attribute name "rewards". and i want to show all cart products rewards point total  in **cart and checkout  summary**

Comment: Question Updated